# Best way to deploy visual studio 2013 project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, deployment

My app is ready to deploy. When I build the app in release modus and send it a couple of friends to test, they can't run it because of missing dll's.

So I used dependency walker to check which dlls they need. Do I really need to search on my computer for the dll's or is there an option that the dll's are in the release building dir?

Answer (score 0):

Your friends computer needs to have the [VS 2013 redistributable packages](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=39315)

You can perhaps build an installer that either downloads these, or installs them as part of your distribution. Or you can tell your "customers" to download and install them from a suitable link.

Comment: Thanks. Whats the best free installer builder?

Comment: That would be closed rather quickly as "opinon-based". I'm a Linux developer so I have absolutely no idea. I think MS has one...

Comment: I've done that, but still after they installed vs 2013 red the app still complains about missing dll's. Whats the profesional solution to deploy an app? I'm still a student so I always need to download the dlls or find them on my computer but that takes time...

Comment: Are you building a release build or a debug build? The redist-package only has the release build libraries. Obviously, if you are using some custom libraries, that would have to be distributed too.